# How to read Excel file based on rowname and column name using Java?

Tags: java, excel, selenium, testing, webdriver

For example consider I have a table like below

```
Student Name | Student Marks | Student Percentage

Santosh      |  85           |82%
Rajesh       |  95           |88%
```

Here column names are Student Name, Student Marks and Student Percentage.

Now I want read this file with row value that is santosh and column name student marks. These are two inputs, depending on that I want to read corresponding cell value. for example that marks :85.

Below code which I tried,

```
String rowValue = "Santosh";




    String columnValue = "Student Marks";

    FileInputStream fis =new FileInputStream("File Name");
    Workbook wb= WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
    Sheet Sheet1=wb.getSheet("sheet1");
    for(int i=1;i<=Sheet1.getLastRowNum();i++)
    {
    if rowValue.equals(Sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue()))
    {
    String marks=Sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();

    System.out.println("values are :- "+marks );
    break;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverFlow. Please take a minute to read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This question is overly broad, and provides no attempted code examples. Either review and edit your existing post, or ask a new, better question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, here is the hint for the answer, first get the rowIndex with rowvalue and secondly get the column index with column value and then read the excel file with rowIndex and columnIndex.

Comment: if anyone want source code, please post your comment will share it..